# Bot activity message not received after publish to production

Tags: c#, botframework, message

My bot is developed in .NET Core 3.1 and i am using **SendActivityAsync** at dialog level twice as shown below.

```
 await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(replyText1).ConfigureAwait(false);
 await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(replyText2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It's working fine in Bot emulator. Below you can find screenshot for the same.
[image]

After publishing bot to production 1st message arrives but 2nd is not. Below is screenshot for the same.[image]

I want same behavior as received in emulator after publishing bot to live.

Comment: if you call `SendActivityAsync()` just once, do you get one message or none?

Comment: Yes, Its works if i use it once. But i need second message too.

Comment: Does it behave the same without `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Yes, same behavior.

Comment: ConfigureAwait(false) is not really required.

Answer (score 1):

You might try instead using `SendActivitiesAsync()` to send multiple messages (as an array of activities) to the user at once. Additionally, I tested it as written using two `SendActivityAsync()` calls in sequence within a `stepContext` in a `Dialog`, and it does work.

However, the second message that you have in the emulator says "Here are some additional findings:", which implies that there is a further external API call or something else your bot is pulling information from. Perhaps you could examine that avenue to see if something external to your bot is timing out, and this ending up with your bot timing out and not sending the second message. You could replace that with a plain text message to test it.

As your question is written, I have no idea what else your bot is doing, so I cannot speak to precisely what that might be.

Here's the docs page on `SendActivitiesAsync()` for your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp